# Functional Equation's induction-Extending from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q_+}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, functional-equations

So I stumbled upon this problem from [UkrMO97](https://imomath.com/othercomp/Ukr/UkrMO97.pdf).

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb{Q}_+\to\mathbb{Q}_+$ which satisfy the conditions:
> (i) $f(x+1)=f(x)+1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}_+$;
> (ii) $f(x^2)=f(x)^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}_+$.

And I can easily see that we can induct on $x \in \mathbb{N}$ using the condition (i) only. I want to extend this to $\mathbb{Q_+}$, by using (ii). And I do not know how to pull that off. Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Given $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, find an integer $n$ so that $(n+a/b)^2$ differs from $(a/b)^2$ by an integer and use that to solve for $f(a/b)$.

More details are hidden below.

> Note that $(b+a/b)^2=b^2+2a+(a/b)^2$.  So, we have $$(b+f(a/b))^2=f((b+a/b)^2)=b^2+2a+f(a/b)^2$$ so $2bf(a/b)=2a$ and thus $f(a/b)=a/b$.